# Error: Text data outside of root node - when installing cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I sometimes get an error when trying to install any cordova plugin ionic (usually after around 6pm GMT+0).

These are with plugins from both npm and GitHub, and the error I get is:

```
Error: Text data outside of root node.
Line: 155
Column: 1
Char: "
```

The install command will be something along the lines of

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information@1.3.1`

It really does not matter what plugin it is, because as mentioned it happens for a number of them, they all get the same error. It will work perfectly ok in the morning, and then suddenly it shuts down.

I have tried on multiple computers, on multiple separate internet connections (from the UK), and I even have a script that reruns the commands if they fail, so it will attempt to install around 20 plugins continuously until they get installed for however long I run my script. I ran it for an hour constantly, and not a single one was installed.

I also checked the status of npm and GitHub if they were perhaps down, but they seemed to be up and running as usual...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Replicated across different computers, across different internet connections, across different plugins? Always that same "ionic cordova plugin add <whatever>"? I don't know ionic at all, but can't you just do "cordova plugin add <whatever>" w/o the ionic part? May be worth a try.

Comment: Hi @ChrisNeve - thank you for that - I have figured out what is going on here - and ultimately the fix for right now is to use cordova directly. If you want to add that as an answer - I will accept it (and probably expand on what I found after)

Comment: Done! And of course, looking forward to reading what you found out.

Comment: Try this command line please `ionic doctor check`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** Based on my comment which helped the asker, and which I was asked to publish as an answer:***

I don't know ionic at all, but I do have some experience with Cordova and never had any issues installing plugins, even on a corporate network.

Try to install the plugin without ionic.

```
cordova plugin add my.plugin.name
```

Comment: Hi @chris-neve - so just a quick update. When you use ionic cordova plugin add - with the latest version of the ionic-cli (v3.19), it seems that it updates your config.xml file. In my case I was using a gulp task which uses sh.exec to install multiple plugins at the same time. As you install plugins, it updates config.xml, but sometimes while adding it adds a incomplete entry in the xml file, for example adding <widget as is.

When that happens - the error above happens, and what I need to do is to remove these incomplete nodes from the xml file and continue.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by an invalid AndroidManifest.xml file. After installing a plugin using `ionic corvoda`, my AndroidManifest.xml got a syntax error and I had this issue when building the APK.
After fixing the syntax error, the build finished successfully.